# Splitting strings through php to query mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I need to split a string in two so I can do a SELECT query in my DB. For example, I have the number '0801'. I need to split that number into '08' and '01'. How do I manage to do that?

Comment: What determines the split? Position? (I.e always the first 2 etc.c) Value? your question is vague.

Comment: The first 2 numbers. It's allways a 4 digit number and I allways need to split it in 2 two digit numbers,

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php

Comment: use if always the first 2   `print_r(str_split($str,"2"));`

Comment: Oh damn. Thank you a lot,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is easy to do using the `substr()` function, which lets you pull out parts of a string. Given your comment that you always have a four-digit number and want it split into two two-digit numbers, you want this:

```
$input = "0801";

$left = substr($input, 0, 2);
$right = substr($input, 2);

echo "Left is $left and right is $right\n";
```

Comment: Wow the other guys just showed me this fucntion but you really went balls deep explaining it. Well done now I trully understand. Thank you a lot. Both of you.

Comment: You're welcome! As the answer helped you, please take the time to mark it as correct so others can benefit too. Google brings a lot of people to Stack Overflow :)

Answer (score 1):

According to your comment

> The first 2 numbers. It's allways a 4 digit number and I allways need
>   to split it in 2 two digit numbers

You can simply use

```
$value = '0801';
$split = str_split($value, 2);
var_dump($split[0]);
var_dump($split[1]);
```

Just keep in mind $value variable should always be of a string type, not int.

Answer (score 1):

you can use [str_split](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-split.php) and [list](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.list.php)

```
$str = '0801';
list($first,$second) = str_split($str,2);

echo $first;
// 08
echo $second;
// 01
```

Answer (score 1):

No one gave a MySQL answer yet...

If you're selecting that number..

```
SELECT 
    SUBSTR(colname, 0, 2) as firstpart, 
    SUBSTR(colname, 2, 2) as secondpart 
FROM table
```